# Mechanism for reaction of beta-ketoacid with AcONa, AcOH with heat

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am unsure of how to go about designing a mechanism for the following molecule's reaction with AcONa and AcOH with heat.
I thought perhaps it may work as a cyclisation reaction, forming an ether; or perhaps a decarboxylation. I've tried many of these mechanisms and none of them seem to give an answer that seems correct.

Any hints/tips would be much appreciated.

[image: molecule]

Comment: Sodium acetate in AcOH is acting as a base, so my first thought is that these are decarboxylation conditions